# Return nameserver and ip server from domain c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working in a formular that input a url and needs to return the nameservers and the IP of the server. I'm trying to do that and search for solutions but i just find how to get the hostname and the ip hostname. Can anyone help me?

Thanks,

Comment: Getting the name servers is a DNS request.

Comment: I can't find in System.Net.Dns something that returns to me that. Just the hostname and the ip. Someone told me about HTTPCONTEXT but it just returns from current http and not from a specific http.

Comment: The framework might not have built-in support, so either use a library or issue your own DNS query.